# Cannot find 'FBSnapshotVerifyView' in scope

Tags: fbsnapshottestcase

I build demo project 'iOSSnapshotTestCaseCarthageDemo' with support via Carthage in Xcode 15.1 on M1 cpu and got this error:

> Cannot find 'FBSnapshotVerifyView' in scope

for this test case included in demo project:

```
func testExample() {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    FBSnapshotVerifyView(view)
    FBSnapshotVerifyLayer(view.layer)
}
```